# Class 'Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpeg' not found

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

Inside an Artisan command I have this

```
 FFMpeg::fromDisk('songs')
            ->open('this.mp4')
            ->export()
            ->toDisk('converted_songs')
            ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Audio\Aac)
            ->save('yesterday.aac');
```

At the top of the file I already added

`use Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpeg;`

I am getting this error

```
Class 'Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpeg' not found
```

I am also using Laravel-zero, and I have tried everything possible. Been stuck on this for hours now, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just Use the following namespace

use FFMpeg;